# On a reference request for the proof that strong convexity and lipschitz continous gradient of a twice differentiable function imply bounded Hessian.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am looking for a reference for the proof of the fact that a twice differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strongly convex of constant $\ell$ and has Lipschitz continuous gradient $\nabla f$ with constant $L$ ( we assume $0< \ell< L$) if and only if

$$    I_{d \times d} \ell   \le  \nabla^2 f(x) \le I_{d \times d} L  \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d  $$

where $I_{d \times d}$ is the identity matrix and with the less than or equal sign we mean that $\nabla^2 f(x) - I_{d \times d} \ell  $ and $ I_{d \times d}L - \nabla^2 f(x)  $ are positive definite matrices.

I see this fact often cited in the convex optimization literature but rarely proved in its entirety.

Comment: This is trivial, right? Lipschitz continuity is a for $\nabla f$, not for $f$ itself. Which of the two inequalities is not obvious?

Comment: @LinAlg I guess I am just very rusty in multivariable calculus but I could prove it only for $d=1$ using the mean value theorem so I went in search for a reference.  If you have a reference please post it, thank you!

Comment: @Monolite There are many equivalent definitions of strong convexity. Which one are you using? $f(y) \ge f(x) + (y-x)^\top \nabla f(x) + \frac{\ell}{2} \|y-x\|^2$?

Comment: @angryavian  That one is the one I use but any equivalent formulation would be fine.

Comment: so which of the two inequalities are you interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition  $$f(y) \ge f(x) + (y-x)^\top \nabla f(x) + \frac{\ell}{2} \|y-x\|^2, \forall x,y$$
is equivalent to $h(x) := f(x) - \frac{\ell}{2} \|x\|^2$ being convex, which in turn is equivalent to $0 \preceq \nabla^2 h = \nabla^2 f - \ell I$.